# In Tempo.js - the JavaScript rendering engine, what is the best way to deal with no results being returned in the JSON array?

Tags: javascript, json, tempo

Using Tempo.js, I would like to be able to render a message if there are no items in the JSON array. As far as i can tell, you cannot put anything inside the 'data-template' as these are not even called if there are no items in the JSON array to loop through. I would imagine this should work something like the example below (???? = a magical command to display if no rows exist):

```
<div data-template-?????>Show this if there is no messages</div>

<div data-template>
    Display each message looped through
</div>

<div data-template-fallback>Sorry, JavaScript required!</div>
```

I cannot find way to do this all through the Tempo.js docs. Have i missed this ? Or is there another way to achieve this ?

I know i could do this is JS before rendering the template, but that kind of defeats the point of keeping the JS and HTML template code seperate so would like to do this completely within the template if possible.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yeah I can't figure out how to do it either. I suppose after your render() call introspect the json array to see if there were any messages then .show() an inline div with your messaging.

Comment: Yeah I could not find any documentation on this.

Comment: I've given up on Tempo JS and moved to Angular. Its the bomb.